# Почему попадает в бесконечный цикл indexOf?

Tags: javascript

```js
let str = 'some string';

let target = 's';
for(let pos = 0; pos !== -1; pos++) {
    pos = str.indexOf(target, pos);
    console.log(pos);
}
```

Почем данный цикл является бесконечным и выводит -1? Хотя в условии задано явно проверка на -1. И как можно исправить при минимуме изменений?

Comment: У вас первый результат равен 0, второй - 5, а далее символ не найден и pos=-1. После выполнения тела цикла управление с `pos` равным `-1` переходит к операции приращения счетчика (`pos++`) и только потом к проверке условия `pos !== -1`. Соответственно условие не выполняется и цикл выполняется заново

Answer (score 2):

Ну отладчик же существует.

Когда `indexOf` вернул `-1`, после вывода происходит `++pos` и проверка `0 !== -1`.

```js
let str = 'some string';
let target = 's';

for (let pos = 0; ; ++pos) {
  if ((pos = str.indexOf(target, pos)) === -1) break;
  console.log(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что когда `pos` становится равным `-1`, ему тут же в конце итерации добавляется `1`.

```js
let str = 'some string';

let target = 's';
let count = 0;
for(let pos = 0; pos != -1 && count < 20; pos++,count++) {
    console.log(pos, str.indexOf(target, pos));
    pos = str.indexOf(target, pos);
}
console.log('done');
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда твой indexOf возвращает `-1` на скобочке `}` (в конце цикла) к `-1` добавляется `+1`, таким образом минимальное значение `0` (цикл бесконечен)

Мне кажется, или ты хотел сделать что-то такое?

```js
let str = 'some string';
let target = 's';
let tf = false;

for(let pos=0; pos < str.length; pos++){
    tf = str.charAt(pos) === target;
    if(tf)console.log(tf, pos);
}
```

Вот твой цикл, но рабочий

```js
let str = 'some string';
let target = 's';

for(let pos=0; pos < str.length; pos++){
    const index = str.indexOf(target, pos);
    if(index !== -1){
        console.log(index, pos); // pos просто для информации
        pos = index;
    }else break;
}
```